# Save function results when a script is executed

Tags: function, save

Pretty new to python. I have a machine learning script, and what I would like to do is, every time the script is run, I would like to save the results. But what I don't understand is if all the code is in one script, how to save the results without overwriting? So for example:

```
auc_score = cross_val_score(logreg_model, X_RFECV, y_vars, cv=kf, scoring='roc_auc').mean()
auc_scores=[]
def auc_log():
    auc_scores.append(auc_score)
    return(auc_scores)
auc_log()
```

Everytime I run this .py file, the auc_scores list will start with blank, and the list won't update until each time the function is executed, but if you run the whole script than obvious the above will execute and start the saved list as blank again. I feel this is fairly simple, just not thinking about this properly from a continuous deployment perspective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be as well to use each result list or zero list as variables of acc_log function, which can leave all function result.
For example,

```
auc_score=cross_val_score(logreg_model, X_RFECV, y_vars, cv=kf, scoring='roc_auc').mean()

#if auc_score is 'int' or 'float', you must conver it to list type 
auc_score_=[]
auc_score_.append(auc_score)

auc_score_zero=[]

def acu_log(acu_score_1,auc_score_2):
    acu_scores=acu_score_1+auc_score_2
    return acu_scores

initial_log=acu_log(auc_score_zero, auc_score_)
#print (initial_log)

second_log=acu_log(initial_log, auc_score_)
#print (second_log)
```

If you want to save each acc_log list on HDD after returning the result at each step, 'pickle module' is convenient for treating it.

I’m not sure this is really what you want, but hope  my answer contribute to solve your question